# PHP MySQL echo won't work properly

Tags: php, mysql, echo

I have this code that is supposed to echo some values from a MySQL database. The first 2 work fine. It echo's properly, it works fine ... until it gets to the title. It echos' the `<title>` and `</title>` and `"XXX |"` but won't display the value. Any Help? Thanks a million!

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $info_array )) {
    echo $row['id'];
    echo "</br>";
    echo $row['name'];
    echo "</br>";
    echo "<title>XXX | "$row['name']"</title>";
};
```

UPDATE:
Thanks to everyone that helped! Turns out that that code had no error. It was an error further up in the code.

Comment: The last echo has some problems. Either you need to escape " with \" or you need to concatenate string with vars like "str1".$var1."str2"

Comment: It's not going to kill you, but you don't need that trailing semi-colon

Comment: So what was the solution? On SO you accept the answer that answered your question instead of just saying "oh hey it's fixed" without giving any resolution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try concatenating your strings with `.`s:

```
echo "<title>XXX | " . $row['name'] . "</title>";
```

Comment: @JosephTorraca: Then you've got some other issues; that's how you concatenate strings with PHP.

Answer (score 3):

That looks like it will give a syntax error.  Put a concat dot around $row['name'] or wrap it in curly brackets.

```
echo "<title>XXX | ".$row['name']."</title>";
```

or

```
echo "<title>XXX | {$row['name']}</title>";
```